# Cant get TRON contract ABI from Trongrid

Tags: tron, tronweb

For some TRON contracts i am not able to get ABI. Eg using https://developers.tron.network/reference#smart-contracts for this one:

contract - TQn9Y2khEsLJW1ChVWFMSMeRDow5KcbLSE

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/getcontract \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"value":"41a2726afbecbd8e936000ed684cef5e2f5cf43008","visible":false}'
```

it does not return ABI. Why it does not return? how to get this ABI not using tronscan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a contract created by another contract.
So there's no chance for the developer to set an ABI.

You should refer to the creator contract's code.